# NodeJS and HTTP: How to send JSON content in a POST/PUT call as a string rather than creating a new key

Tags: json, node.js, angular, http

I built an API service that will process REST requests and use them to perform CRUD operations on a MongoDB instance.  This application is standalone (by design) and should be a passthrough for anything that calls it.  My other application that I built in Angular is calling this API to interact with my MongoDB instance.  I have been trying to construct my JSON payload from a form, which works fine.  I get something like:

```
{ "_id":"111111111", "name":"herp", "address":"derp", "city":"foo", "state":"bar", "zip":"11111", "phone":"111-222-3333"}
```

I am then trying to take that JSON and send it along to the service, but something is getting lost in translation once the service gets a hold of it and my variable name that contains the JSON object is being turned into an actual key in the request, with the JSON as its value.  I am calling the service like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' })
};

updateStuff(update){
   console.log("Sending: " + JSON.stringify(update) + " for update");
   return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/api/test/_update', {dbName:"testDb",collection:"testing",update}, httpOptions);
}
```

Which logs:

```
Sending: {"name":"blah","address":"111 Anystreet","city":"MyCity","state":"NY","zip":"11111","phone":"555-111-2222","_id":"5ba914df13236f7a6ea3e233"} for update
```

So I know that right before the call is made, the data is fine.  However, on the other side, it sees the following when it gets the data:

```
Received request: {"dbName":"testDb","collection":"testing","update":{"name":"blah","address":"111 Anystreet","city":"MyCity","state":"NY","zip":"11111","phone":"555-111-2222","_id":"5ba914df13236f7a6ea3e233"}}
```

instead of what I intended, which is below:

```
{"dbName":"testDb","collection":"testing","name":"blah","address":"111 Anystreet","city":"MyCity","state":"NY","zip":"11111","phone":"555-111-2222","_id":"5ba914df13236f7a6ea3e233"}
```

How do I tell the HTTP request to send the data itself rather than constructing a new key with the name "update" and sticking the payload in there as its value?  I tried JSON.stringify, but that ends up sending the same thing, but with a bunch of backslashes in front of all the parenthesis.  It still sends it all in a key with the name "update" as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
{dbName:"testDb",collection:"testing",update}
```

The statement above is shorthand for this:

```
{dbName:"testDb",collection:"testing",update:update}
```

What you're looking to do is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Spread_properties):

```
{dbName:"testDb",collection:"testing",...update}
```

Which is shorthand for this:

```
const data = {dbName:"testDb",collection:"testing"};
for (let key in update) {
    if (update.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        data[key] = update[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, that is awesome - thanks!  I never knew about the ... shorthand before and always thought that was just people's way of demonstrating "etc."